# A few of my addresses that have funds show empty through my node

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoin-qt-setup, reindex, sparrow-wallet

I have recently connected sparrow wallet to my own node to get away from using a private electrum server.

But some of the addresses I have bitcoin in are not being recognized. I know they have funds because I checked the addresses on 'mempool.space'. Before I get too far I want to explain that this is not a gap limit issue because these are the first three addresses in my wallet. Not later ones.

So I closed Bitcoin Core, opened 'bitcoin.conf' and entered:

```
 reindex-chainstate=1
```

Someone recommended I try doing this to go through utxos I think.
It seemed like it was doing OK, but every single time it eventually stopped responding.

So now I'm wondering if I should just use 'reindex=1' through 'bitcoin.conf' or entering the command line and using `bitcoin-qt -reindex`.  This would make it so I completely redo the entire blockchain right?

I might have to do it because things are not working. When I was building the blockchain for the first time, I know that my laptop had fallen asleep a few times. Maybe that caused a block to be corrupted? I've since figured out how to keep my laptop from falling asleep.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the wallet, use the `rescan=XXX` rpc, where XXX is a block height where you want to start from.

Try looking at `debug.log` if something is corrupter, it'll tell so. If something is corrupted, or no apparent cause is found, you should use `reindex`. This might take a while, tho.