# Bitcoin core balance isn't working properly

Tags: bitcoin-core, sparrow-wallet

while moving funds to my multi-sig, my balance on bitcoin core sometimes is subtracting. Even though my balance on sparrow is correct and is connected to my node. So it should be getting all of its information from my node. Bitcoin core also shows my list of transactions (though sometimes even when I do a payment to self the debit and credit shows 0 instead of normally showing the amounts)

---

Comment: Is it possible you're seeing the effects of Change Addresses? Your sparrow wallet may be sending change outputs to new, non-visible addresses that are part of the wallet, but perhaps you have not imported in Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Could this be a symptom of the switch in backend you described in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118706/13866 ?